# Reorder single columns in R, without specifying all columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an R data frame with many columns. On the right end of the frame I have created new columns. Now I would like to see this new column somewhere on the left. I usually work with dplyr.

Example: 
This is what I have:
    `FirstName|LastName|Height|Width|Nationality`

This is what I want:
    `FirstName|LastName|Nationality|Height|Width`

Of course, I could do a 
    `select(....)`
but this way I would have to specify all(!) columns. I am looking for something like 
    `select*(FirstName,LastName,Nationality)`
without having to specify all, but only the first columns and leave the rest as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select(FirstName, LastName, Nationality, everything())
```

Or if you have many columns "on the left" that you don't want to name (only 2 in this example):

```
select(1:2, Nationality, everything())
```

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.